# Python Regular expression does not match on year month combination

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, date

I use Python 3.8.6 with regular expression to find an English month+year combination in a string. Therefor I use the following code:

```
import re

regMonthPatternEn = 'an(?:uary)?|eb(?:ruary)?|march?|apr(?:il)?|may|jun(?:e)?|jul(?:y)?|aug(?:usst)?|sep(?:tember)?|oct(?:ober)?|(nov|dec)(?:ember)'
regYearPattern = '.*([1-3][0-9]{3})'
text = 'january 2018'
resultMonthEn = re.match(regMonthPatternEn,text)
resultYear = re.match(regYearPattern,text.lower())
print(text)
print(workExperiencePeriodYearList)
if (resultMonthEn and resultYear):
    print('Match')
```

I expect that is will return "Match" in the console as output. But it returns nothing. Can you please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Should't it be `jan(?:uary)?` and not `an(?:uary)?`  ?

Comment: Which are the strings you are hoping to match? (And do they really drop the first letter from Jan and Feb, and misspell August with two s:es?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of [`re.match()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match):

> If zero or more characters at the beginning of string match the
> regular expression pattern, return a corresponding match object.
> Return None if the string does not match the pattern; note that this
> is different from a zero-length match.

Your regex does not match the `j` of `january` (and neither the `f` for `february`).

This regex will work for your test string:

```
regMonthPatternEn = 'jan(?:uary)|feb(?:ruary)|march?|apr(?:il)?|may|jun(?:e)?|jul(?:y)?|aug(?:usst)?|sep(?:tember)?|oct(?:ober)?|(nov|dec)(?:ember)'
```

Edit: as @triplee has commented, there is an extra `s` in `augusst`, which you might want to fix.

Comment: Probably still fix the spelling of August, too.

Answer (score 3):

Instead use `datetime` module:

```
import datetime 
text = 'january 2018'
try:
  dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(text,'%B %Y')
except ValueError:
  print("Not match")
else:
  print("Match")
```

Comment: Great answer but it doesn't match the short form "jan 2020" format that the OP was looking for. You could add `dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(text,'%b %Y')` to the except branch to catch that date format too.